# 3列入れ子配列[[i,j,k],[l,m,n],...]から、2列(i=lかつj=m)が一致しているときのみ、もう一列を足し合わせたい(k+n...)

Tags: python, array

3列入れ子配列[[i,j,k],[l,m,n],...]から、2列(i=lかつj=m)が一致しているときのみ、もう一列を足し合わせたい(k+n...)と考えております。

言葉でうまくまとめられないので、画像を用いて説明すると現在、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のような、配列のデータを持っています。
このうち先頭の二列が一致する配列の場合、末尾の一列を足し合わせる処理を行いたいです。

(例)[-0.01,37.225,49.526255],[-0.01,37.225,37.288825])の場合に、
　 →[-0.01,37.225,86.81508]

全配列数は6000ほどで、先頭の二列が一致するのは一回のみとは限りません。
上記の処理により最終的には、先頭の二列が同じ組が全配列内に存在しないようにしたいです。

お手数をお掛けして申し訳ございませんが、どなたか知恵を授けていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

[追記]
現在考えているコードを張ります。勉強を始めたばかりで、意味不明なコードになっているかも知れません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 試したコードは何もありませんか？

Comment: 「配列の次元」の考え方を間違えているようです。質問に書かれているのは2次元の配列(リスト)でしょう。1行が3列で行数は特に規定されいない可変行数の配列(リスト)では？ あるいは例えば3つの各列の数字が縦・横・高さの3次元座標値を表しているということなのかもしれませんが、それは配列としての次元とは別の物でしょう。

Comment: @merinoさん ご返信ありがとうございます。拙いですが作成中のコードを張ります。

Comment: @kunifさん　ご連絡ありがとうございます。全く以てご指摘の通りです。質問は修正します。

Comment: pandasのDataFrameに変換すればこちらの記事の応用で出来るでしょう。[Pandas で複数列の GroupBy と Aggregate を行う](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python-pandas/pandas-groupby-aggregate-multiple-columns/)

Comment: kunif さん　ご返信ありがとうございます。さっそく試してみて上手くいきました！(また、PandasのDataFrameは便利ですね。その後のmatplotlibやseabornを使ったグラフ作成まで完了することができました。)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

data_list_ACF_2 = [
    [-0.01, 37.225, 49.526255],
    [-0.0098, 37.225, 11.429136],
    [-0.0096, 37.225, 7.31264],
    [-0.0094, 37.225, 2.089326],
    [-0.01, 37.225, 37.288825]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_list_ACF_2)
data_list_ACF_3 = df.groupby([0, 1], sort=False, as_index=False)[2].sum().values.tolist()

pprint(data_list_ACF_3)

#
[[-0.01, 37.225, 86.81508],
 [-0.0098, 37.225, 11.429136],
 [-0.0096, 37.225, 7.31264],
 [-0.0094, 37.225, 2.089326]]
```

Comment: `df.groupby([0, 1], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()...` (`[2]`ナシ)でもよいのでは？
＆ これは質問側の問題だけど `sort=False`で大丈夫なのかどうかですね

Comment: `[2]` を付けるかどうかはお好みで。

Answer (score 0):

元の並びは保持していません。Pandas使用された方が良いかと思いますが、numpy.ndarrayで実装してみました。

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(4, 10, (10, 3))
print(a)
#array([[5, 8, 4],
#       [5, 4, 6],
#       [5, 8, 9],
#       [5, 7, 8],
#       [4, 4, 7],
#       [8, 7, 8],
#       [9, 6, 6],
#       [4, 8, 8],
#       [9, 9, 4],
#       [7, 7, 4]])

first = np.unique(a[:,0])
second = np.unique(a[:,1])

result = []
for f in first:
    for s in second:
        u, counts = np.unique((np.where(a[:,0] == f)[0].tolist()+np.where(a[:,1] == s)[0].tolist()), return_counts=True)
        if len(np.where(counts > 1)[0]) > 1:
            result.append(np.hstack((a[u[counts != 1]][0, 0:2], a[u[counts != 1],2].sum())).tolist())
        else:
            tmp = a[np.where((a[:,0] == f) & (a[:,1] == s))[0]]
            if len(tmp) > 0:
                result.append(tmp[0].tolist())
                
result = np.array(result)
print(result)
#array([[ 4,  4,  7],
#       [ 4,  8,  8],
#       [ 5,  4,  6],
#       [ 5,  7,  8],
#       [ 5,  8, 13],
#       [ 7,  7,  4],
#       [ 8,  7,  8],
#       [ 9,  6,  6],
#       [ 9,  9,  4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

並びは保持しない (pandasとかじゃない) Pythonでの方法
(別解の初期処理そのまま利用させてもらいました)

```py
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(4, 10, (20, 3))

grpkey = lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]
res = [k +[sum(m[-1]for m in g)]
         for k,g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=grpkey), grpkey)]


# 結果の表示
for k,g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=grpkey), grpkey):
    print(k, list(g))
# [4, 8] [array([4, 8, 8])]
# [5, 4] [array([5, 4, 4])]
# [5, 5] [array([5, 5, 6])]
# [5, 6] [array([5, 6, 7])]
# [5, 7] [array([5, 7, 8]), array([5, 7, 6]), array([5, 7, 7]), array([5, 7, 6]), array([5, 7, 5])]
# [5, 8] [array([5, 8, 4])]
# [6, 4] [array([6, 4, 6])]
# [6, 9] [array([6, 9, 8])]
# [7, 7] [array([7, 7, 4])]
# [7, 9] [array([7, 9, 6]), array([7, 9, 8])]
# [8, 5] [array([8, 5, 5]), array([8, 5, 8])]
# [8, 9] [array([8, 9, 4]), array([8, 9, 4])]
# [9, 8] [array([9, 8, 4])]

display(res)
# [[4, 8, 8],
#  [5, 4, 4],
#  [5, 5, 6],
#  [5, 6, 7],
#  [5, 7, 32],
#  [5, 8, 4],
#  [6, 4, 6],
#  [6, 9, 8],
#  [7, 7, 4],
#  [7, 9, 14],
#  [8, 5, 13],
#  [8, 9, 8],
#  [9, 8, 4]]
```